# Zip reactive flow with itself

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I'm using Java Reactor Core, and I have a reactive `Flux` of objects. For each object of the Flux I need to do an external query that will return one different object for each input. The newly generated `Flux` needs then to be zipped with the original one - so the items of the 2 Flux must be synchronized and generated in the same order.

I'm just re-using the same flow twice, like this:

```
 Flux<MyObj> aTest = Flux.fromIterable(aListOfObj);

Flux<String> myObjLists = aTest.map(o -> MyRepository.findById(o.name)).map(o -> {
  if (!o.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("Fallback to empty-object");
    return "";
  }
  List<String> l = o.get();
  if (l.size() > 1) {
    System.out.println("that's bad");
  }
  return l.get(0);
});

Flux.zip(aTest, myObjLists, (a, b) -> doSomethingWith(a,b))
```

Is it the right way to do it? If the `myObjLists` emits an error, how do I prevent the `zip` phase to skip the failing iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally opted for using `Tuple`s and `Optional`s (to prevent null-items that would break the flux), so that I don't need to re-use the initial `Flux`:

```
Flux<Tuple<MyObj, Optional<String>>> myObjLists = Flux.fromIterable(aListOfObj)
  .map(o -> Tuples.of(o, Optional.ofNullable(MyRepository.findById(o.name))
  .flatMap(t -> {
    if (!t.getT2().isPresent()) {
      System.out.println("Discarding this item");
      return Flux.empty();
    }
    List<String> l = t.getT2().get();
    if (l.size() > 1) {
      System.out.println("that's bad");
    }
    return Tuples.of(t.getT1(), l.get(0));
  })
  .map(t -> doSomethingWith(t.getT1(),t.getT2()))
```

Note that the `flatMap` could be replaced with a `.map().filter()`, removing tuples with missing Optional items